# How to make an inventory system for the Blender Game Engine

Tags: game-engine

I want to make an inventory for an adventure game. The game is first person and the items to be collected will be used later in other parts of the game. To give you an idea, the game is something like an HOPA (Hidden Object Puzzle Adventure) game, here is an example:

[image: example hidden object game example]

I have already watched tutorials available on YouTube but they don't seem appropriate. The game is a point and click so no keyboard will be used.

Comment: This site is not the place to ask for tutorials https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?302504-Series-Basic-inventory-system-for-the-Blender-Game-Engine

Comment: I have already had a look at that tutorial but as I said, it's not a shooter it's a point and click adventure game with no keyboard involved!

Comment: See this http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/62/regarding-questions-and-answers-as-tutorials

Comment: Also correct me if I'm wrong, but an inventory is an inventory, shooter game or otherwise. It is supposed to contain/organize/display in-game items, the underlying concept should be the same, regardless of how you control it, point being there must be something useful about that tutorial.

Comment: Sure! The difference is that when you have an inventory for weapons, you call the inventory by clicking a keyboard key, you can even do that without using any script just with logic bricks. You can also switch weapons by assigning a key to each but in the point and click case, you have to do everything only with the mouse and I have just started using game logic so I was hoping that someone else had done that. I believe that a python script would help the most. Otherwise, I will have to go through all the tutorials available on the subject and work something out by myself. Thanks anyway!

Comment: "Otherwise, I will have to go through all the tutorials available on the subject and work something out by myself." Yes, that is why people made all those other tutorials - not to provide and end-all, but to teach you how to make your own.

Comment: Ok guys, thanks for your feedback I'll try hard to learn from those tutorials then.

Comment: Also see this video [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7DM_oSwqXfE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7DM_oSwqXfE)

Comment: Yes, I have already followed that tutorial but the guy doesn't really explain what's he doing while writing the code and the code is so small it's really hard to follow. I have already written to Goran Milovanovic as Miracles Happen asking for a finished blend file or the python code in text format - so far he hasn't answered yet. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, what you are asking is quite a big task and you first need to make a saving function so that items are saved for later on and don't just disappear. That needs python, and luckily this exists: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ffws4ijjk-0

Then you need to make a second scene that has the HUD, which is basically just an image of some boxes where items would go. Then you would add an empty in each slot, and then set it up so that when you pick up an item (or interact with an item) the empty would add the object into the HUD slot where the empty is located. And then you would make a property for each item you can possibly get, so that when you have the item it can add 1 to the property. When you use the item, it would take away the 1 from the property and get rid of it from the HUD, by ending the object that represents the item. Finally, you need to add a property that keeps track of how many items you have. For example, if the HUD could hold 6 items, then you need to set it up so when you try to pick up a 7th item, it would not let you because the value is 6 already. Once this value is decreased to 5 or less, then it would let you pick it up.

This is mostly just my ideas and I have't actually ever done this, but I strongly believe it would work. It might be a bit tricky setting up which empty adds the HUD object though.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I have in mind. As far as I understand, using python in combination with the logic bricks is the best way to do it. I think the HUD should be done in an overlay scene. I love ThaTimst3r's tutorials, they are very clear and I'll definitely check the tutorial you suggested. I know how to store variables and now I'm learning how to save objects and manipulate their behavior in python. There is so much to learn but everything is really interesting. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You are welcome, and yes I did mean make the HUD as an overlay. I probably just poorly explained it

Comment: You explained it very well, it's me that I still haven't learned all the technical stuff... Feel free to contact me again if you come across any other useful tips related to this matter. Thanks again!